# How to send a list of arguments to Chaincode?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am working with the Hyperledger Fabric, I want to write a chaincode in go lang which takes list of arguments which contains a list in it.

For example: client will be calling chaincode function with parameters passed are [uname,job,[21,23,45]].

Can anyone help me in reading data in chaincode?

Answer (score 0):

4 years have passed, but I write the answer if  somebody needs it. You can send the third argument as a string and then convert it to a string list.

your method signature will be like this :

```
func (s *SmartContract) SomeMethod(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, arg1 string, arg2 string, strList string)
```

Then you can unmarshal strList paramether as a list of strings using a code like this :

```
var stringList []string
errAsset := json.Unmarshal([]byte(methodArg), &stringList)
    if errAsset != nil {
        fmt.Print(errAsset)
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can send them as ["uname","job","21","23","45"], and in chaincode you can store the arguments by assigning them to your asset.